# How do I fix my JFrame not opening, the compiler gives me no errors, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

[Technically not a [Duplicate]] I know this has happened before (There is a bug where my JFrame will not open when I compile my game, how do I fix this [duplicate]) and MadProgrammer answered:"Game.main isn't doing anything. Since its the main entry point for the program, it will need to do something before something can happen" but now that Game.main does something I don't see the answer.

I tried recompiling and checking for errors, none, someone else even got it to work. How can I fix this

Game.java:

```
package com.hypopixel;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.applet.*;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Thread thread;
    private Boolean running = false;

    public Game() {
        new Window(800, 600, this);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }
    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

Window.java:

```
package com.hypopixel;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Window extends Canvas {

    public static int BlockSizing = 4;

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Window(int Wwidth, int Wheight, Game game) {
        JFrame Window = new JFrame();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Wwidth, Wheight));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        Window.add(game);
        Window.pack();
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window.setTitle("HypoPixel");
        Window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Window.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
/*

Credits:

Just another Java Programmer

MadProgrammer

*/
```

manifest.txt is the same

I expected the JFrame to open (Cuase someone else was able to got it) and it would not open.

Comment: For me it opens, although at minimum size (only a titlebar with some icons). And minimum size it is because you set minimum and preferred size on the `Window` instance but never add it to the `JFrame`. To the `JFrame` you add the `Game` instance, but do not set minimum and preferred size on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there's a number of things which are "off"

Starting with...

```
public Window(int Wwidth, int Wheight, Game game) {
    JFrame Window = new JFrame();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Wwidth, Wheight));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    Window.add(game);
    Window.pack();
    Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Window.setTitle("HypoPixel");
    Window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Window.setVisible(true);
    game.start();
}
```

Apart from the fact that there is already a class called `Window` in `java.awt`, which is confusing, you use the variable name `Window`, which is more confusing.

`Window` extends from `Canvas`, but you never actually use it.  Calling `setPreferredSize` and `setMinimumSize` because `Window` is never actually added to anything and it's commonly recommend against doing so, favouring instead to override these methods, so as to prevent accidentally changing their values.

From `Game`, you call `Window` ... it's kind of weird way to be doing things, as it's not really `Game`s responsibility to be making the window, rather, it's the other way around.

Personally, I'd start with a dedicated entry point, whose responsibility is to load and prepare the environment and show the first screen, for example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Game());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Make sure that the [`manufest.mf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) so that it's `Main-Class` property points to this class.

I'd also update `Game`, so it overrides `getPreferredSize`.  I'd also take a look at your `start` and `stop` methods.

```
public synchronized void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    running = true;
}
```

What happens if this is called twice?  You should be checking the state of the `Thread` before creating a new one

```
public synchronized void stop() {
    try {
        thread.join();
        running = false;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This isn't going to do anything, as `join` is blocking, so the state of `running` will never change.

Also, because of Java's memory model, you may find that even setting `running` to `false` before calling `join` doesn't work.  Instead, you should be using an [atomic variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html) (and using `Boolean` is probably going to cause a bunch of other issues, as you're referencing the memory location and not the actual value)

I would recommend having a read through [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Thread thread;
    private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public Game() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running.set(true);
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running.set(false);
        if (thread == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}
```

> the IDE I use (NetBeans) will not let me run the java file

From the "Projects" tab, select the `Main` class/Java File, right click and select "Run File"

[image: Run file in netbeans]

Alternatively, with `Main` open in the editor (and selected), press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Next, make sure `com.hypopixel.Main` is set as the projects "main class"

- Right click the project node in the "Projects" tab and select "Properties"

[image: Properties]

- Select "Run" from the options down the right side, verify that "Main Class" is set as `com.hypopixel.Main`, if not, click <kbd>Browse...</kbd> and select it from the available options

[image: Options]

Comment: thanks, I did not realize how much really was not working! Maybe the code I was using was outdated, heres where I am getting it from: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gir2R7G9ws&t=40s", outdated?

Comment: @CyleLinin One of the, repeated, issues I have is, youtube tutorials tend to be terrible, in my experience, they're not intended to teach "good" practice so much as show "how" to achieve a particular goal.  For example, in the above code, I would argue that `Game` shouldn't be responsible for managing the thread, that's part of the core engine's responsibility, `Game` really should be only focused on been a rendering surface, but that's me.  And, yes, we get a lot of "I'm following a youtube video..." questions, which tend to be answered with "don't follow it" ;)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to find a tutorial for making a 3D game? also the code you gave does not produce a JFrame.

Comment: @CyleLinin *"also the code you gave does not produce a JFrame"* - Yes it does, I ran it before posting it, you MUST run the `Main` class (it needs to be the main entry point).  *"Can you please tell me how to find a tutorial for making a 3D game"* - I doubt there is one.  You'll need to use a number of sources to build up a solution.  It will also depend on which 3D engine you're trying to use.  I might recommend taking the time to look at JavaFX as it has better inbuilt support for this

Comment: The manifest file is configured with that in mind " Main-Class: Main " in Main.java and when I compile it to get T.jar it will not open a JFrame labelled 'Testing' as indicated by the code.

Comment: @CyleLinin My personal suggestion is to focus on solving “a” issue, then figure out how the piece fits into the overall puzzle. “Main loops” are well documented and discussed, update the state, render the state, fps calculation, repeat; entity management is widely discussed. I’d try looking at the available, open source, engines, they’ll give you a lot of useful info and ideas, maybe focus on using one or two and see what the differences are and how you might use them

Comment: *"it will not open a JFrame"* - Then there is something else wrong - put in a `System.out.println` statement in the `main` method, see if `Main` is been run at all.  Is `Main` in a package?  Java has issues with classes been placed in the default package

Comment: Nope, does nothing. No errors, No IDE errors, nothing, and yes it is in a package, package name:"com.hypopixel"

Comment: Okay, can you run it from the IDE?  Run the class directly (from the IDE)? `Main-Class: Main` should look more like `Main-Class: com.hypopixel.Main`, based on the available information. At the moment, all you have is a misconfiguration - this is why I linked [working with the manifest file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) tutorial above

Comment: the IDE I use (NetBeans) will not let me run the java file. also I don't know if this will help but when I compile it generates 3 .class files Main.class, Main$1.class, and Game.class

Comment: From the project navigator, select the `Main` class (java file), right click and select "Run File" or, while the file is open in the editor, press [Shift]+[F6]

Comment: whenever I run Main (in NetBeans) it argues this at me:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Game
 at com.hypopixel.Main$1.run(Main.java:20)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 a

Comment: Do a "Clean and Build" first, then run the `Main` class

Comment: how do I fix THAT?

Comment: Are both `Main` and `Game` in the same project?  Do you have them in the correct packages and are the imports correct. When you compile the code, do you get any error messages?

Comment: @CyleLinin What you seem to need is a good tutorial on Netbeans